# Unexpected segmentation error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, queue, iostream, cout

I wrote a really simple program, but it's crashing when I try to write the size of a queue (created with STL). I have no idea why, please help.

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, i, x, cut = 0;
    queue<int> que;
    vector<int> vec;

    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        vec.push_back(x);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        que.push(vec[i]);

    while (!que.empty()) {
        cout << que.size() << '\n';
        cut += que.front();
        while (que.front() <= cut)
            que.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will `que.front() <= cut` be when `que` is empty? It seems you are assuming it will be false. Review this assumption. Either that, or perhaps you intended to put that condition into an `if` instead of a `while`.

Comment: Also a style issue -- if you know you want to loop over all the elements of the vector, drop using separate variables that supposedly holds the the number of entries.  Instead, use the `vector::size()` function.  I'm speaking of the `n` variable you are using in the second `for` loop -- there is no need for it at that point.  I know the program right now is simple, but using the vector to tell you its size is a habit you should get into.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I will consider that in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because you call `front` while the queue is empty.
Just check if the queue is empty in your inner loop:

```
#include <queue>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, i, x, cut = 0;
    queue<int> que;
    vector<int> vec;

    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        vec.push_back(x);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        que.push(vec[i]);

    while (!que.empty()) {
        cout << que.size() << '\n';
        cut += que.front();
        while (!que.empty() && que.front() <= cut )
            que.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to verify that inner loop indeed. I have just begun using STL and I'm not used to verify every possible thing that would crash. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually crashing on the line:

```
while (que.front() <= cut)
```

Because you have a loop that may be true for the whole queue. The next line pops a value. At some point, your queue is empty and `que.front()` will crash.